# How to retrieve connection string from the below files

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Here i am using windows forms application with vb.net

I have defined a key in AppConfig file as `add key="EnvironmentToConnectTo" value="DEV"`

[image]

This key is referred in an other file for the connection string. This file name is KMMiddleTier.xml

`<ConnectionKey Key="DB_DEV" ConnectionString="Data source=LKWENTSQLDEV3\ENTDEV32K8R2;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=TAMSdev;User Id={0};Password={1};"  timeout="200" UserPasswordKey="DBUser"/>`

[image]

I want to retrieve the connection string into a variable and i want to use this connection string for some other purpose. Please let me know how can i retrieve connection string value from these files.

I have tried something like below, but yes it did not work

`Dim connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DB_DEV").ConnectionString`

Comment: so do you have a config file and an xml? Is the xml part of your project?

Comment: yes sir it is part of the project, i want to read that attribute value of connection string

Comment: Gotcha - if that is the case you are going to have to code for the xml. you will have to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432185/retrieve-single-attribute-value-from-an-xml-doc-element

Comment: What if i have xml file in different project but same solution. How to specify the path. For an example i have solution name : `Traffic` which has two projects TAMS and Terminal. And TAMS has xml file and how to use it in Terminal Project

Comment: @user1030181 Your code would work if you had the connection string in the app.config. Why do you need it in a custom xml file?

Comment: @WilliamXifaras because the framework is structured this way.

Comment: @user1030181 Ok, so again - your code won't work. You have to write something custom. Read up on LINQ to XML. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/linq/564/linq-to-xml-tutorials-examples

Comment: Nope - the solution doesn't matter. From my knowledge you cannot share between projects in the same solution. You could always save the xml somewhere on the server and have your program reference it or add it to your project

Comment: Tried Something like this `Dim xe As XElement = XElement.Load("..\\..\\KMMiddleTier.xml")
        Dim name = From nm In xe.Elements("ConnectionKey") Where nm.Element("Key") = "DB_DEV" Select nm.Element("ConnectionString").Value` but does not work

Comment: lol I got distracted and forgot about this :)

Answer (score 0):

The code would be more like the below

```
'Load the xml
Dim xe As XElement = XElement.Load("..\\..\\KMMiddleTier.xml") 

Dim ReturnValue As New List(Of String)
'loop through each xmlnode in your selected node " ie your connection string
For Each node As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("//ConnectionKeys")
    ' then get the node attribute ie your connection key and add it to your string
    ReturnValue.Add(node.Attributes("Connection Key").Value)
Next
```

Comment: I want retrieve "DB_DEV" key connection string value without loop. Using LINQ is that possible

Comment: Prob, you will have to research linq I don't use it. I like the old school way. The loop would just loop through the node connection string and add what ever value you want to the string