# How to read attribute value of xml

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How can i read attribute value of a xml.

I have this below xml and i am working with windows forms vb.net

[image]

I tried something like this below but does not work. I want to read connection string value

```
        Dim xe As XElement = XElement.Load("..\\..\\KMMiddleTier.xml")
    Dim name = From nm In xe.Elements("ConnectionKey") Where nm.Element("ConnectionKey").Attribute("Key") = "DB_DEV" Select nm.Element("ConnectionKey").Attribute("ConnectionString").Value.FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432185/retrieve-single-attribute-value-from-an-xml-doc-element) might help

Comment: I dont want to loop. i want a single string value

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim xmlDoc as XMLDocument
    Dim xmlNodeList As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/KMMiddleTierSecurity/ConnectionKeys/ConnectionKey")


    Dim strConnectionKey As String = xmlNodeList.Item(0).Attributes("ConnectionString").Value''''
```

This might help.

Comment: Without Index of Item as (0) I want to use connection key as shown in image above `DB_DEV`

Comment: Based on key i want to retrieve the connection string

Comment: any suggestion how can i do this

Comment: Don't think you can achieve this without looping.